# Isomorphism of affine varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, complex-geometry

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ and $Y\subseteq\mathbb{C}^m$ be two complex affine varieties (zero sets of systems of polynomials). Suppose that
$$f:X\to Y$$
is a polynomial map, or more precisely, it is given explicitly by
$$f(x)=(f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x)),$$
where $f_i:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ are polynomials in $n$-variables.

> **Question:** If $f$ is a bijection, is it necessarily an isomorphism of complex affine varieties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is **no**. A standard counter example is the following: let $X = \mathbb{C}$ and $Y = V(y^2-x^3) \subset \mathbb{C}^2.$ Then the map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ given by $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ is a bijection, but not an isomorphism.

One way to see that it couldn't be an isomorphism is to note that $X$ is smooth while $(0,0)$ is a singular point of $Y$.